# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and ETW

Tags: c#, azure, logging, dll, azure-storage

An external dll is hanging and I think it's caused by the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` dll.  As my application relies on the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` dll, I was wondering if it might be possible to utilise ETW to output logs from the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it might be possible to utilise ETW to output logs from the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage dll?

Azure Storage Client library allow us to log Azure Storage requests from client-side. We can see the details of the requests your client sends to the Azure Storage services and the responses it receives from the log. To enable it, we need to configure the diagnostics sources in your app.config or web.config file. You could use following configuration to send the output logs to ETW.

```
<system.diagnostics>                                                                         
  <sources>
    <source name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage">
      <listeners>
        <add name="EventLogListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="EventLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
                        initializeData="AzureStorageLog" />
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

[image]

In addition, to make upper configuration work. the user which run your application need have enough privilege to add logs to Windows Event Logs. On my side, I need to run my sample application as administrator.